# How to clear specific gradle cache files when running the "Clean project" command?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have added the following task in my project's build.gradle file:

```
task('clearLibCache', type: Delete, group: 'MyGroup',
        description: "Deletes any cached artifacts with the domain of com.test in the Gradle or Maven2 cache directories.") << {
    def props = project.properties
    def userHome = System.getProperty('user.home')
    def domain = props['domain'] ?: 'com.test'
    def slashyDomain = domain.replaceAll(/\./, '/')
    file("${userHome}/.gradle/caches").eachFile { cacheFile ->
        if (cacheFile.name =~ "^$domain|^resolved-$domain") delete cacheFile.path
    }
    delete "${userHome}/.m2/repository/$slashyDomain"
}
```

I'd like this task to be executed when I hit the "Clean project" menu, and only in this case.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "Clean project" menu item under the hood appears to do a couple of things (based on the output of the Gradle Console window when you click it):

- A gradle clean, the equivalent of calling `./gradlew clean`
- Generate sources and dependencies for a debug build, including a mockable Android sources jar if needed.

I would make your task a dependency for the Gradle clean task, so that whenever the project is cleaned, this task is also invoked. This can be achieved by adding the line `clean.dependsOn clearLibCache` in your `build.gradle` after you declare the task.